# How to align multiple author's name, roll, institute in titlepage in beamer?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I have to make a slide with two authors that means two person(a team) will present the slide in a presentation. But, I can't align team member's name and roll.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author{Md.Al-Helal\\SH-51\hspace{3cm}Jobayed Ullah\\EK-107}
\institute{Computer Science \& Engineering}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author{Jianhua Tang\\ Wee Pen Tay\\ Tony Q. S. Quek}
\institute{IEEE Transactions on Wireless Communications, vol 14, no. 9}
\date{September 2015}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: enter link description here]

This may help litle https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42709750#42709750

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write names in two `parbox`-es. And don't forget to fill the optional `author` parameter with the names that you want in footer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author[Md. Al-Helal, Jobayed Ullah]{\parbox{2.5cm}{\centering Md.Al-Helal\\SH-51}\hspace{1cm}\parbox{2.5cm}{\centering Jobayed Ullah\\EK-107}}
\institute{Computer Science \& Engineering}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author{Jianhua Tang\\ Wee Pen Tay\\ Tony Q. S. Quek}
\institute{IEEE Transactions on Wireless Communications, vol 14, no. 9}
\date{September 2015}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Stack it!  The `stackengine` package allows multiple items to be vertically stacked, with either constant gap between items (short stack) or with constant baselineskip (long stack).  They can be stacked so that the last item sits on the baseline (a stack) or that the first item sits on the baseline (an understack) or centered around the baseline (a centerstack).  Within a stack, there can be left, right or center horizontal alignment, the default being center.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author{\Longunderstack{Md.Al-Helal\\SH-51}\hspace{3cm}%
  \Longunderstack{Jobayed Ullah\\EK-107}}
\institute{Computer Science \& Engineering}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation with  elastic service scaling in Cloud Radio access network}
  \author{Jianhua Tang\\ Wee Pen Tay\\ Tony Q. S. Quek}
\institute{IEEE Transactions on Wireless Communications, vol 14, no. 9}
\date{September 2015}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I accept your answer, but you can give explanation that is understandable for anyone.

Comment: @alhelal I have added some explanation.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Is there something `stackengine` cannot do? Probably not :)

Comment: @samcarter It's neither a floor wax nor a dessert topping, http://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/shimmer-floor-wax/n8625?snl=1